# How should I parse a file in Ruby on Rails to store in a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a simple form for users to upload a file, which will be stored in a database.  I also want to display all the submitted files in the database with their name and a link to download the file. Schematically, what's the best way to do this in Rails/how should I store the file in table (which fields should my table have? etc). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would use paperclip gem with the upload to s3 instead of file system

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

checkout the README, most of the examples are for an image, but works with non-image files as well

Answer (score 0):

use paperclip to upload file, you can store images/file in your database as well as in s3 (AWS)
See below link how to use paperclip in rails with example

Here is the steps how to upload file using paperclip in rails

```
http://patshaughnessy.net/2009/4/30/paperclip-sample-app
```

for github

```
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip
https://github.com/websymphony/Rails3-Paperclip-Uploadify
```